# how to dynamically load multiple components in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want 2 different components from 2 different buttons to work dynamically on my homepage. but I was only able to run one of them.

This is my dynamic-load.service

```
async loadComponent(component: ComponentLoad, viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    let _component: any = null;

    switch (component) {
      case ComponentLoad.SolarwindsPanelComponent:
        _component = (await import("../../dialogs/notification/solarwinds/solarwinds-panel/solarwinds-panel.component")).SolarwindsPanelComponent;
        break;
      case ComponentLoad.PeriodicalCheckPanelComponent:
        _component = (await import("../../dialogs/periodicalCheck/periodical-check-panel/periodical-check-panel.component")).PeriodicalCheckPanelComponent;
        break;
    }

    viewContainerRef.clear();
    return viewContainerRef.createComponent(_component);
  }
```

and this is my header.component

```
@ViewChild(DynamicLoadDirective, {static: true})
  dynamicLoadDirective: DynamicLoadDirective;


loadSolarwindsComponent() {
    const containerRef = this.dynamicLoadDirective.viewContainerRef
    this.dynamicLoadService.loadComponent(ComponentLoad.SolarwindsPanelComponent, this.dynamicLoadDirective.viewContainerRef)
  }

  loadPeriodicalCheckComponent() {
    this.dynamicLoadService.loadComponent(ComponentLoad.PeriodicalCheckPanelComponent, this.dynamicLoadDirective.viewContainerRef)
  }
```

I tried different things in the documents I found, but I could not run both at the same time.

Thanks for your help.